# Filter array of array within a complex object and return that object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, lodash

I have tried to write pipe like so:

This is what I need to achieve

> the filter will allow any objects(`items/ItemModel[]`) that don't include selected colors (`res/FilterMenuDataModel`) to be hidden

> selected Colors mean's `colorIds` array.

```
 transform(items: ItemModel[]): Observable<ItemModel[]> {
    return this.menuElementsDataService.filterMenuFinalDataChanged$.pipe(
      map((res) => {
        if (!res) {
          return items;
        }

        return filter(items, (i) => 'need your help here';
      })
    );
  }
```

*item.model.ts*

```
export interface ItemModel {
  itemId?: number;
  itemName?: string;
  colorIds?: number[]; // one array is this
}
```

*filter-menu-data-model.ts*

```
export interface FilterMenuDataModel {
 
  colorIds?: number[]; // the other array is this
}
```

**Note:** `res` object has `FilterMenuDataModel` properties.

I have tried many things/many hours without any luck yet. Do you know how to do that? I have used [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) here. But Javascript way is also fine hence I can convert it to Lodash later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the aim is to find items which have no colorIds in common with items selected by a filterMenu. Lodash offers [intersection()](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersection), so the filter predicate can be a test for an empty intersection, as follows...

```js
const items = [
  { itemId: 0, itemName: 'zero', colorIds: [32, 33, 34] },
  { itemId: 1, itemName: 'one', colorIds: [33, 34, 35] },
  { itemId: 2, itemName: 'two', colorIds: [34, 35, 36] },
];

// only item one above does not include colors 32 and 36
const filterMenuData = { colorIds: [32, 36] };

const hideTheseItems = items.filter(item => {
  return _.intersection(item.colorIds, filterMenuData.colorIds).length === 0;
});
console.log(hideTheseItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```